# show the form only if submit is not set 

Tags: php

I am trying to show the form only if submit is not set, and if set then upload file and show link to the same page so that a new file could be uploaded again.

It shows the form even after I click on the submit button. I have not added an upload script now.

```
<body>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $output_form == 'no';
        echo 'hiiiii';
    }
    else {
        $output_form = 'yes';
    }
    if($output_form = 'yes')
    {
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="file" name="uploadpic"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of every other post on SO.

Comment: BTW your indentation is all messed up!

Comment: ahh.. nice low hanging fruit and then SO wants to verify that I'm human. oh well :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
if($output_form == 'yes')
```

Answer (score 2):

- `$output_form == 'no';` should be `$output_form = 'no';`
- `if ($output_form = 'yes')` should be `if ($output_form == 'yes')`

`=` is assignment, whereas `==` is a comparison.

Also, your `form` will use `GET` because you did not [ask it to use `POST`](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html) with `method="POST"`.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your method on the form element.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

You can also use `print_r($_POST)` to see what's in the array.

Here's an example of it working, as well as the code.

http://www.wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7018639.php

Comment: I don't get the down vote either, he can't use enctype on the default get method of a form, he has to set the method to post.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($output_form = 'yes')
```

should be

```
if($output_form == 'yes')
```

The way you have it now, you're assigning a value.

Answer (score 0):

You doing assignment, use comparison:

```
if($output_form == 'yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're actually SETTING the no value as well:

```
 $output_form == 'no';
```

Should be

```
$output_form = 'no';
```

Comment: It's 'still not working' because defects are littered throughout your code. Note how I included 'as well' due to your `yes` problem as mentioned in 4 other answers.